# How to Show Serial Number inside 'span' tag in nested hierarchy

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Below is the code that I am going to use,

```
<template name="App_ViewTasks">
    <body  class="skin-blue sidebar-mini" style="height: auto;">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content">
          <div class="row">
            {{#each tasks}}
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-danger">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <h3 class="box-title">
                                <span class="label label-default css-serial"> </span>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
        </section>  
      </div>
    </body>
</template>
```

I want an auto serial number to be generated inside the span tag just like below.

[image]

I am trying to achieve it using css with below code.

```
.css-serial {
  counter-reset: serial-number;  /* Set the serial number counter to 0 */
}
.css-serial {
  counter-increment: serial-number;  /* Increment the serial number counter */
  content: counter(serial-number);  /* Display the counter */
}
```

I am missing the element mapping, that's it! any help would be deeply appreciated.

> Note: Not necessary that css has to be used to achieve this, you may suggest much better implementation.

Comment: No Down Voters justified their action. I humbly request to at least tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close with your solution.

`content` is only used on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

The `counter-reset` was being reset for every span, so I've added `:first-of-type` to the selector.

```css
.content-wrapper .content .row .col-xs-12:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: serial-number;
  /* Set the serial number counter to 0 */
}

.css-serial {
  counter-increment: serial-number;
  /* Increment the serial number counter */
}

.css-serial:after {
  content: counter(serial-number);
  /* Display the counter */
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-danger">
          <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">
              <span class="label label-default css-serial"> </span>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-danger">
          <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">
              <span class="label label-default css-serial"> </span>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-danger">
          <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">
              <span class="label label-default css-serial"> </span>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-danger">
          <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">
              <span class="label label-default css-serial"> </span>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-danger">
          <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">
              <span class="label label-default css-serial"> </span>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

### edit

Based on update question: You need to change the selector for the `counter-reset`. From your html, I've changed it to `.content-wrapper .content .row .col-xs-12:first-of-type`. It would be better if you add a class to the outer div for prettier css.

Comment: I does not work for me, It show 1 1 1 1 for all records. It is set to `1` all the time. May be I'll need to update my question to get exact answer.

Comment: Chrome latest version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Me too, and the result for me is 1-8. Did you run the snippet above, or in your webpage? Maybe other things on your page affected it.

Comment: @klenium: My class herirachy is different. It works only when span tag used. But I have nested tags with classes. I an trying to map the nested class in css to achieve this.

Comment: @AnkurSoni I've updated my answer to take into account your html hierarchy.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King: Thanks a ton for the time you gave on this question. I really appreciate your efforts.